# Email Templating with Delimiters

Tags: c#, asp.net

In DasBlog the template uses the following syntax, for example:

<h1><%= MyMacro() %></h1>

inside a txt file, and my query is, how this is evaluated at run time?  Does the author of DasBlog use the AspCompiler programatically?

Is there an Evaluating statement I am missing or is the author simply using Regular Expression search and replaces?  I doubt the latter but I need to ask regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.Web namespace contains methods to compile text like this. One way to do it, when you have the physical path, are:

```
    IHttpHandler pageInstance = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(viewPath, physicalPath, HttpContext);
    pageInstance.ProcessRequest(HttpContext);
```

Comment: I cannot vote you up yet either as my reputation is only 11 :-(  Cheers again